# Extract monomials with a certain structure from a given polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I have a long polynomial such as

```
a x^2+ bx^2y+cx^2y^2 +d x^3y^4+e x^4y^3+f y^2+g xy^2
```

Consider an example problem as follows: I want to output the monomials (along with their coefficients) which have y^2 in them and then write down a polynomial using them. In other words, if y^2 is not contained in the monomial, I want to set its coefficient to 0 and write down the resulting polynomial. For example, the above polynomial will lead to the following

```
0 x^2+ 0 x^2y+cx^2y^2 +0 x^3y^4+ 0 x^4y^3+f y^2+g xy^2 = cx^2y^2+fy^2+gxy^2
```

Can MonomialList extract the monomials with a certain structure like the above example?

Comment: I assume you want spaces between adjacent letters (e.g. `b * x^2y`, not `bx^2y` which equals `(bx)^2y` since `bx` is treated as a single variable.

Comment: `y^2 Coefficient[expr, y^2]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expr = a x^2 + b x^2 y + c x^2 y^2 + d x^3 y^4 + e x^4 y^3 + f y^2 +  g x y^2;

y^2 Coefficient[expr, y^2]
```

> ```
> (f + g x + c x^2) y^2
> ```

```
Expand @ %
```

> ```
> f y^2 + g x y^2 + c x^2 y^2
> ```

```
TeXForm @ %
```

> $c x^2 y^2+f y^2+g x y^2$

You can also use

```
Plus @@ Cases[ _. y^2] @ expr

ReplaceAll[Except[_. y^2, _Times] -> 0] @ expr

Expand @ First @ Cases[_. y^2] @ MonomialList[expr, y]
```

Answer (score 4):

If the polynomial is expanded, then perhaps this:

```
Replace[
 a x^2 + b x^2 y + c x^2 y^2 + d x^3 y^4 + e x^4 y^3 + f y^2 + 
  g x y^2,
 term_ /; FreeQ[term, y^2] -> 0,
 1]
(*  f y^2 + g x y^2 + c x^2 y^2  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Toward this end, we need to test all terms of the polynomial on level 1. We can do this using "Replace" with a level specification. We then need to test if the term does not contain "y^2" and set these terms to zero. This can be done with a corresponding rule:

```
poly = a  x^2 + b x^2 y + c x^2 y^2 + d x^3 y^4 + e x^4 y^3 + f y^2 + 
  g x y^2
Replace[poly , x_?(FreeQ[y^2]) :> 0, {1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[MonomialList[expr], ! FreeQ[#, y^2] &, Total], True]

(*f y^2 + g x y^2 + c x^2 y^2*)
```